# Crash with unwrapped nil value after attempting to initialize an AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, console

```
//
//  playSoundsViewController.swift
//  recordVoice
//
//  Created by david on 11/08/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Tomcorp. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class playSoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    var receivedAudio:RecordedAudio!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.enableRate = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func slowVoice(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer.rate = 0.5
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func fastVoice(sender: UIButton) {
            audioPlayer.stop()
            audioPlayer.rate = 2.0
            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0
            audioPlayer.play()
    }


    @IBAction func stopButtonSounds(sender: UIButton) {
            audioPlayer.stop()
    }

    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


//
//  recordSoundsViewController.swift
//  recordVoice
//
//  Created by david on 11/08/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Tomcorp. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class recordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!

    var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
    var recordedAudio:RecordedAudio!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        stopButton.hidden = true
        recordButton.enabled = true

    }

    @IBAction func recordButton(sender: UIButton) {

        recordButton.enabled = false
        stopButton.hidden = false
        recordingLabel.hidden = false
        //record voice



        //Inside func recordAudio(sender: UIButton)
        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String


        let recordingName = "my_audio.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
        println(filePath)

        var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

        audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.record()

    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if(flag){
        recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()
        recordedAudio.filePathUrl = recorder.url
        recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("stopRecording", sender: recordedAudio)
        }else {
            println("Recording was not successfully")
            recordButton.enabled = true
            stopButton.hidden = true
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "StopRecording"){
            let playSoundsVC:playSoundsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! playSoundsViewController
            let data = sender as! RecordedAudio
            playSoundsVC.receivedAudio = data

        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {
        recordButton.enabled = true
        recordingLabel.hidden = true
        //Inside func stopAudio(sender: UIButton)
        audioRecorder.stop()
        var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        audioSession.setActive(false, error: nil)
    }

}

//
//  RecordedAudio.swift
//  recordVoice
//
//  Created by david on 13/08/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Tomcorp. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class RecordedAudio: NSObject{
    var filePathUrl: NSURL!
    var title: String!
}

//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  recordVoice
//
//  Created by david on 11/08/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Tomcorp. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

This is what its says on the console:

Optional(file:///Users/david/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/12D7F78E-5FFA-4964-9AEE-F395D962264F/data/Containers/Data/Application/A5B7545C-2800-495C-B016-07C3DF010D97/Documents/my_audio.wav)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: these its the part its wrong

Comment: these its the part its wrong: audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl, error: nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TOMCORP, your code is full of novice errors. Some are directly responsible for the crash, some will create problems sooner or later down the line, some are just failure to keep up with good programming practice.

Everything is explained in comments.

If nothing else be sure to understand "MAJOR ERROR 2" because that has to do with the ViewController lifecycle. Getting the capitalization wrong on the segue identifier is also a critical error.

By the way, there appears to be no provision to return from the playback VC. You need some kind of button that performs a `dismissViewControllerAnimated()`.

The following code worked fine on my Xcode 6.4 / iPhone simulator 8.4. I left out the boilerplate `AppDelegate` code. Also be sure to put back the 'import' statements that I've left out below.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

// FIX of Error 11
let stopRecordingSegue = "stopRecording"

// Error 1: (Style) Class names should always be capitalized
class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    // MAJOR ERROR 2: viewDidLoad() runs **BEFORE** prepareForSegue(). So it was looking for the
    // 'recordedAudio' instance variable but prepareForSegue had NOT YET had a chance to
    // initialize it.

    // viewDidLoad is the WRONG place for DYNAMIC, RUNTIME initialization.

    // Instead we make a custom method, called by prepareForSegue(), so we're in full control
    // of the flow of data from VC to VC.
    func prepareAudio(receivedAudio: RecordedAudio) {
        var err: NSError?
        // Error 3: check carefully for all error conditions
        if let ap = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl, error: &err) {
            audioPlayer = ap
            ap.enableRate = true
        }
        else {
            assertionFailure("Exiting program, couldn't create recorder: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    // Error 4: (Style) Don't have overridden methods that do nothign but call super().
    // The clutter just creates confusion. didRecieveMemoryWarning function removed.

    @IBAction func slowVoice(sender: UIButton) {
        // Error 5: Handle case where player did not get initialized
        if let ap = audioPlayer {
            ap.stop()
            ap.rate = 0.5
            ap.currentTime = 0.0
            ap.play()
        }
        else {
            println("No audioplayer available in slowVoice!")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func fastVoice(sender: UIButton) {
        // Error 5: Handle case where player did not get initialized
        if let ap = audioPlayer {
            ap.stop()
            ap.rate = 2.0
            ap.currentTime = 0.0
            ap.play()
        }
        else {
            println("No audioplayer available in fastVoice!")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopButtonSounds(sender: UIButton) {
        // Error 5: Handle case where player did not get initialized
        if let ap = audioPlayer {
            ap.stop()
        }
        else {
            println("No audioplayer available in stop!")
        }
    }

    // Error 6: (Style) Leave out dead code that's commented out. Creates more confusing clutter.
}

class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var recordedAudio: RecordedAudio!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Error 7: Initialization: All one-time initialization must go in viewDidLoad(), not when the user
        // pressed a button. Sometimes redundant initialization is not actually harmful, but it's a terrible
        // programming habit nonetheless.
        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

        let recordingName = "my_audio.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
        println(filePath)

        // Error 8: Don't create unnecessary variables just to do one-time initialization. Confusing clutter.
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

        // Error 9: Don't use 'nil' for error object; receive the error and check it
        var err: NSError?
        audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: &err)
        if let e = err {
            assertionFailure("Exiting program, couldn't create recorder: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            println("successfully created audio recorder")
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // Error 10: overriding conventions: Failure to call super of a built-in method like this one
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        stopButton.hidden = true
        recordButton.enabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func recordButton(sender: UIButton) {
        recordButton.enabled = false
        stopButton.hidden = false
        recordingLabel.hidden = false

        audioRecorder.record()
    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()
            recordedAudio.filePathUrl = recorder.url
            recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent
            // Error 11: sender should be the actual initiating VC
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(stopRecordingSegue, sender: self)
        }
        else {
            println("Recording was not successful") // Error 12: Grammar
            recordButton.enabled = true
            stopButton.hidden = true
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Error 13: Not using a defined constant string, you've messed up capitalization
        if segue.identifier == stopRecordingSegue {
            let playSoundsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaySoundsViewController
            // REST OF FIX OF MAJOR ERROR 2: send in data to a method so runtime initialization code can run
            playSoundsVC.prepareAudio(recordedAudio)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {
        recordButton.enabled = true
        recordingLabel.hidden = true
        audioRecorder.stop()
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, error: nil)
    }
}

class RecordedAudio: NSObject{
    var filePathUrl: NSURL!
    var title: String!
}
```

Comment: hello thnx for your comment but it not work i dont know why its says that its a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You replaced your viewDidLoad() with mine and still got that error?  On what line?

Comment: i got a error in different part of the code every audioRecorder make me change for audioRecorder! and then works but dont reproduce the record sound

Comment: Change 'audioRecorder' into 'audioRecorder'? Change something into the same thing? How do you expect us to understand? You will need to post all of your code. Ideally zip up the entire project and post a link to it.

Comment: Ah never mind. I see. Because I changed the declaration of audioPlayer (not audioRecorder) into explicit optional ('?' vs '!'), you have to unwrap it when you use it. Yes, that was intentional to force you to check for nil, or force-unwrap, since you're still learning Optionals. Anyways, it's still most efficient to see everything in context, i.e. post entire zip file including sound resources. If you're new to Swift / Xcode, a variety of errors could be contributing to the failed behavior.

Comment: Where? Nothing was changed.

Comment: hello @BaseZen i post other question with all the code please check thnx

Comment: hello @BaseZen here i complete the post with all the others files code please help me thnx